# Is removing all renderflex errors in Flutter a must?

Tags: flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-renderflex-error

So i have been trying to find some information about how bad it is not to fix a renderflex error. I have a custom app bar which changes based on the screensize.

The searchbutton is an animated container in a row, which is stacked on top of a row which holds the appbar title and some buttons for in between the app bar title and the search button.

The problem is that when I resize the window on desktop or web, the search bar (which is based on screenwidth - ktoolbarheight *2) will not immediatly change its size causing the last button (which comes after the search bar) to go out of bounds and cause a renderflex error.

Ive tried several approaches to solve it, including wrapping the row in SingleChildScrollView, but it wont fix the problem. But when I run flutter --release, it doesn't actually give an error. It just has a short delay on resizing the search bar.

Is it necessary to remove all render flex errors, or is it okay to leave in some (one in my case) as long as they don't break the app functionality? I've tried to find info on this online but i've only found ways to fix the error (which didn't actually fix my specific error).

Comment: Good question. I wonder about the same. I don't like to see the errors, but I guess there is no other way.